# get form query parameters values

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am performing ajax call on my .aspx page

Passing some values which contain characters like `'/' , '&' , '-' , '.'` hence using `encodeURIComponent`

```
$('#divDialog').html('<p>Loading Please wait...</p>').dialog({ title: 'Processing Information', modal: true, resizable: false, draggable: false }).load('ajaxExecute.aspx?Fn=CAO2',
    {
        'EmploymentType': encodeURIComponent($('#cmbEmploymentType').val()), 'NatureIncome': encodeURIComponent($('#cmbIncomeNature').val())
    },
    function (response, status, xhr) {
        $('#divDialog').dialog('close');
        // Some Code
}
});
```

i am trying to get those values in c#

```
if (Request.Form["EmploymentType"] != "" && Request.Form["EmploymentType"] != null) string sEmpType = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["EmploymentType"]);
```

`QuickWatch` Shows values in `Convert.ToString(Request.Form["EmploymentType"])`

As `Car%2FTruck%2FBoat%2FPlane%20Dealer`

**I tried** `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToString(Request.Form["EmploymentType"]))` But Same result

How can i get string `Car/Truck/Boat/Plane Dealer` As it is in variable ?

Comment: That string is already encoded.. you need to `Decode` it.

Comment: @Dan-o used decode it works but not able to store value in variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Request.Form, this will only work for from submits, not for ajax requests. Have a look at C# [WebMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) they will turn the request data into C# objects for you. heres an [example project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66432/Consuming-Webservice-using-JQuery-ASP-NET-Applicat)

in ajaxExecute.aspx.cs:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static void DoFoo(String EmploymentType, String NatureIncome){
     string sEmpType = EmploymentType;
 }
```

Javascript:

```
 $(...).load('ajaxExecute.aspx/DoFoo',
     {
        'EmploymentType' : $('#cmbEmploymentType').val(),
        'NatureIncome':  $('#cmbIncomeNature').val()
     }
     // rest of arguments
  }
```

Comment: this method will initiate auto. when this call `ajaxExecute.aspx?Fn=CAO2` is made ?

Comment: You have to change it to call ajaxExecute.aspx/DoFoo

Comment: Done this but it coudnt able to hit break point on static method. It a Web Application ASP.NET & C#. Not a Web Service !! Will it Still Work ?

Comment: Yes you can add them directly to the ajaxExecute.aspx.cs file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688951/calling-webmethod-ina-aspx-cs-file-using-jquery-ajax