# HTML page to Server side stored proceedure call

Tags: html, stored-procedures, client-server

I am new to client server programming but not programming in general, I have searched the web before asking this but I cannot seem to get a good answer so here is what I want to do.

I want to create a HTML page it will have a button and an edit box (I can do this)
When the button is pressed I want it to call a stored procedure on an SQL box and return the result in some form (popup windows will do here).

My problem is that I do not understand how to get from my HTML page to the server, do I need to call an aspx page followed by an aspx.cs page and and execute the stored_proceedure from there, if so how do I get from HTML to aspx and back, or is there some other method?
I assumed this would be simple to do but after researching I am finding it's not.

Any help example or links would be great, many thanks

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Ajax call to get from the html page to the .cs file to call your stored procedure. An example is here: [Calling webmethod ina aspx.cs file using jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688951/calling-webmethod-ina-aspx-cs-file-using-jquery-ajax)

Then in the success function of the ajax call, you can create a dialog box with the information returned from the stored procedure.

Comment: This is a webmethod, however it works the same for a regular method.

Comment: Thanks Lucien, not exactly what I want but it lead me towards and answer so it get's my vote :-)

Comment: @JamesB Glad I could help! Didn't want to tell you exactly how because then you wouldn't learn ;)